# is there any way to add default image in ACF image field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add default image options in WordPress admin (we can say set default options in image field ) when I try to create an image field using ACF thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can put the code like below in your functions.php

```
add_action('acf/render_field_settings/type=image', 'add_defult_image_field');
    function add_defult_image_field($field) {
        acf_render_field_setting( $field, array(
            'label'         => 'Defult Image',
            'instructions'      => 'Appears when creating a new post',
            'type'          => 'image',
            'name'          => 'defult_value',
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much its work for me for front end and backend both thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Taken from https://stupop010.medium.com/how-to-set-a-default-image-on-acf-wordpress-977d38869b78, you need to create an action to a `default_value` field. After that, add a filter that checks when the user did not select any image, and then loads the default value.

```
add_action('acf/render_field_settings/type=image', function ($field) {
    acf_render_field_setting( $field, array(
        'label'         => __('Default Image','acf'),
        'instructions'  => __('Appears when creating a new post','acf'),
        'type'          => 'image',
        'name'          => 'default_value',
    ));
});

add_filter('acf/load_value/type=image', function ($value, $post_id, $field) {
    if (!$value) {
        $value = $field['default_value'];
    }
    return $value;
}, 10, 3);
```